# R best practices : for CRAN, should you optimize or keep the base methods

Tags: r, cran

I'm writing for my package on CRAN, on the way to optimize the speed.

I've seen one main problem, which is that the "base" (stats actually) methods for time series are quite slow, especially when you work with same tsp.

```
set.seed(1)
a <- ts(rnorm(480),start=2010,freq=12)
b <- ts(rnorm(480),start=2010,freq=12)
library(microbenchmark)

ts_fastop <- function(x,y,FUN) {
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  tspx <- tsp(x)
  if (any(abs(tspx - tsp(y)) > getOption("ts.eps"))) stop("This method is only made for similar tsp", call. = FALSE)
  ts(FUN(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(y)),start=tspx[1L],frequency = tspx[3L])
}
identical(ts_fastop(a,b,`+`),a+b)
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(ts_fastop(a,b,`+`),a+b,times=1000L)
# Unit: microseconds
#                  expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
#  ts_fastop(a, b, `+`)  13.7  15.3  24.1260   17.4  18.9 6666.4  1000
#                 a + b 364.5 372.5 385.7744  375.6 380.4 7218.4  1000
```

I think that 380 microseconds, for a simple `+` on a few vars, is way too much.

However, as I was shortcuting these methods, I wonder what's the best practices :

- if anyone shortcuts main functions, I guess it makes it less easy for R core team to manage upgrades
- the readability of the source is better if it is written a+b than ts_fastop(a,b,`+`)

So what is anything advised regarding that ?

Thanks

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. You should mention the package containing `ts_fastop` and the `library` statement you are using.

Comment: @Bhas Hi, the definition of ts_fastop is just above. It's not from a package it's my example

Comment: I would just ask how to do it rather than "best practices" since the latter suggests opinion based answers and those are regarded as off topic on SO.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck as I'm merely an inexperienced CRAN contributor (my first package has been published a month ago), I thought "best practices" as something objective, ie not coding preferences but something close to CRAN policies/advises. As I prefer to contribute wisely.

Comment: By the way @G.Grothendieck is there a place other than SO that is convenient to ask, about R, questions with a subjective answer ? Ie to ask advices, not answers

Comment: There is also r-help.  On SO it's often just a matter of asking questions in a way which does not encourage opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a subclass of `ts` in which case both can coexist.  This should work for constructing `fast_ts` objects from `ts` objects, plain vectors, `zoo` and `xts` objects and others for which an `as.ts` method exists.

```
as.fast_ts <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.fast_ts")
as.fast_ts.fast_ts <- identity
as.fact_ts.default <- function(x, ...) structure(as.ts(x, ...), 
  class = c("fast_ts", "ts"))

Ops.fast_ts <- function(e1, e2) {
   result <- match.fun(.Generic)(c(e1), c(e2))
   structure(result, tsp = tsp(e1), class = c("fast_ts", "ts"))
}

# test

set.seed(1)
a <- ts(rnorm(480),start=2010,freq=12)
b <- ts(rnorm(480),start=2010,freq=12)
af <- as.fast_ts(a)
bf <- as.fast_ts(b)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a+b, af+bf)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that your answer is a nice way to make it "cleaner".

Comment: I guess you likely meant as.ts, in the first line, in order not to remove the tsp attribute.

Comment: Good point. I have expanded it further to explicitly handle several incoming classes.